# Positioning of nodes in chain complex with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I want to get a chain complex as below:

[image]

To get this, I used this code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain] {
    \node[on chain] {$\underset{v \in \Delta_0 ^0} \bigoplus I(v)$} ;
    \node[on chain] {$0$}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

but the positioning of direct sum is not correct on the result.

How can I set the position of direct sum correctly as the image? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please  add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: it is not clear, why you need `tikz` for this simple equation ...  see if `$\displaystyle\bigoplus_{v \in \Delta_0 ^0} I(v) \to 0$` gives what you like to obtain (put in single node or use as equation in text)

Answer (score 4):

As Zarko says, it is not clear why you need [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to do this, and you can instead use

```
 \[\bigoplus_{v \in \Delta_0 ^0} I(v) \longrightarrow 0\]
```

If you really wants to use [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) then I'd recommend a `matrix of math nodes`.

The following [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) shows how to do this as a simple equation, using a matrix of math nodes and using the chains library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains}
\begin{document}

\[\bigoplus_{v \in \Delta_0 ^0} I(v) \longrightarrow 0\]

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,
        column sep=10mm, nodes={anchor=center}]{
      \displaystyle\bigoplus_{v \in \Delta_0 ^0} I(v)&0\\
     };
     \draw[->](M-1-1)--(M-1-2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, every join/.style=->] {
      \node[on chain] {$\underset{v \in \Delta_0 ^0} \bigoplus I(v)$} ;
      \node[on chain, join] {$0$}; }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

The `nodes={anchor=center}` in the styling for `\matrix` ensures that the arrow from `(M-1-1)` to `(M-1-2)` is horizontal, these nodes are the shorthand that tikz provides for the matrix entries in row 1 and columns 1 and 2, respectively. I have also "stealth" arrows.

With the chains example note that you need to specify which nodes to join, by adding `join`, and that I have set `every join/.style=->` to make the join an arrow rather than an edge.

Answer (score 1):

If you persist to use `tikz` (and not consider my comment above), then see if the following modification of the first *Andrew's* example with `tikz` is acceptable:

```
\documentclass[tikz, preview, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, baseline]% added "baseline"
\matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes,
             column sep=7mm]% removed options for node
{
\displaystyle\bigoplus_{v \in \Delta_0 ^0} I(v)&0\\
};
\draw[->](M-1-1.east |- M-1-2) -- (M-1-2);% changed coordinates for arrow
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]